# Document Library - Show Only document inside of folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, filter, caml

I have gotten a big document library. I must show only documents which are in specific folder. How could I show these documents? I have got many folders, but I want to show only the content of one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following CAML query:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Lookup'>FolderName</Value>
      </Contains>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

and CAML query options:

```
<QueryOptions>
   <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
   <OptimizeFor>FolderUrls</OptimizeFor>
</QueryOptions>
```

you could specify to retrieve only items from a specific folder named `FolderName`

> `QueryOptions` element is used for specifying `Scope` property, in our
>   case scope option is set to `Show all files and all subfolders of all folders`

### How to customize CAML of a List View via SharePoint Designer (SPD)

Let's say we need to display items from a folder named `Orders`

Steps:

1. Open List View form page in SPD (AllItems.aspx for a default view)
2. Replace `Query` element with the following one:
   `<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value
   Type='Lookup'>Orders</Value></Contains></Where></Query>`
3. Insert the following element after `Query` element: `<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes
   Scope='RecursiveAll'/><OptimizeFor>FolderUrls</OptimizeFor></QueryOptions>`

That's it.

**Update**

In SharePoint 2013 instead of step 3, specify attribute `Scope='RecursiveAll'` for a `View` element.

Comment: And how get Scope folder View in Sharepoint 2013 ?

Comment: Where is Query Element in Designer 2013

Comment: Open the form page where list view resides, for example default view page  for a Documents library is located here: /Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx. Find the List View web part declaration and then just follow the steps provided in the answer.

Comment: I done on a View but nothing show:

<View Name="{74E77CC8-640A-41EF-9E96-96C086C78652}" Type="HTML" DisplayName="Materiały Promocyjne" Url="/dokumenty_qumak/Dokumenty/Forms/Materiay Promocyjne.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/dlicon.png?rev=23" ><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Lookup'>Audyty</Value></Contains></Where></Query><QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll'/><OptimizeFor>FolderUrls</OptimizeFor></QueryOptions><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/><FieldRef Name="LinkFilename"/>

Comment: <FieldRef Name="CheckoutUser"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View></XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>

Comment: I confirm that it does not work as expected in SharePoint 2013  since, it seems, QueryOptions does not affect in XLV. 
The solution, instead of inserting QueryOptions element (step 3), update View element by specifying attribute Scope="RecursiveAll"

Comment: The answer has been updated.

Comment: Thats work greate but i only wont before click to see in first section before click, and next show next folders view.

Comment: I only want to Show only the files and subfolders of a specific folder.

Comment: Worked perfectly with SPD 2013